Convergence of a sequence defined by a linear recurrence with converging coefficients
Consider the sequences of positive real numbers $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$, $(b_n)_{n \geq 0}$, and $(c_n)_{n \geq 0}$, converging to $a$, $b$, and $c$, respectively, with $a \neq b$. If $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that
$ a_n X_{n+1} + b_n X_n = C_n,
$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
show that $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is convergent and determine its limit.
Assuming that $(X_n)$ converges to some limit $L$, we take limits on both sides of the recurrence relation:
$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( a_n X_{n+1} + b_n X_n \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} C_n.
$
Since $X_n \to L$, $X_{n+1} \to L$, $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$, and $C_n \to c$, we have:
$
a L + b L = c.
$
$(a + b) L = c \implies L = \frac{c}{a + b}.
$
Therefore, if $(X_n)$ converges, it must converge to $L = \dfrac{c}{a + b}$.
It remains to prove that $x_n$ converges which is the more difficult part. Any help in proving this is appreciated.

The condition
$ a_nx_{n+1}+b_nx_n=c_n$ implies that $x_{n+1}\le c_n/a_n$ and $x_n\le c_n/b_n.$ As $a>0$ or $b>0,$ the sequence $x_n$ is bounded.
Let $$y_n= x_n-{c\over a+b}$$
Then the sequence $y_n$ is bounded and $$ay_{n+1}+by_n=(a-a_n)y_{n+1}+(b-b_n)y_n+a_ny_{n+1}+b_ny_n\\
= (a-a_n)y_{n+1}+(b-b_n)y_n+c_n-{c\over a+b}(a_n+b_n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$
We will show that $y_n\to 0.$ If $a=0$ or $b=0$ we get $y_n\to 0.$ Thus we may restrict to the case $a>0,$ $b>0.$
Assume by contradiction that $y_n\not\to 0.$ Thus there exists a subsequence $y_{n_k}$ such that $y_{n_k}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}y\neq 0.$

$b>a>0.$  We get $$y_{n_k+1}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}  -{b\over a}y $$ By iteration we obtain
$$y_{n_k+m}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} (-1)^m{b^m\over a^m}y$$ We get a contradiction as the sequence $y_n$ is bounded, while $\{b^m/a^m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ is unbounded.
$a>b>0.$  Then $$y_{n_k-1}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}-{a\over b}y$$ By iteration we obtain
$$y_{n_k-m}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} (-1)^m{a^m\over b^m}y$$ We get a contradiction on the same basis as in the first case.


The part with the recurrence relation for $y_n$. Are you allowed to take the limit and say it’s zero since we only know that $y_n$ is bounded but we know nothing about monotonicity?

What if $a_n$ tends to a=0. Wouldn’t c_n/a_n tend to infinity meaning that x_n would be unbounded?

This case is contained in my answer. See the part before "Assume by contradiction"

How does the contradiction occur if m varies and we take k going to infinity?

In the last formula $m$ is fixed. Only $k$ tends to $\infty.$

But if m is fixed then how does that imply the contradiction with the bounds . That’s a bit unclear to me

If $y_n$ is bounded say $|y_n|\le C $ for alll $n$ then $|y_{n_k-m}|\le C.$ Thus $(a^m/b^m)|y|$ is bounded by $C.$ This is impossible as $a^m/b^m\to \infty$ when $m\to \infty$ for $a>b>0.$ Similar argument works for $b>a>0.$

Can we say m tends to infinity if we  said that m is fixed?

We got $(a^m/b^m)|y|\le C$ for every fixed $m.$ This is impossible if $a>b>0.$

Can we only have one limit instead of both k and m going to infinity simultaneously to avoid limits within limits to make it less confusing?
